# IIS Rewrite is not working across different domain

Tags: c#, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

**Updating this question as per my latest scenario after correcting based on the comments **

I have installed ARR

I have followed this post https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 to avoid common mistakes

I have hosted 2 IIS sites with few ".html" pages in that.

Below is the Rewrite Rule I have it in my HTMLSite1 web config file.

```
    <rule name="Rewrite Page 3 to Page 4">
      <match url="Page3.html" />          
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^htmlsite1$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://htmlsite1/Page4.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
    
    <rule name="Rewrite HTML Site 1 Page 1 to HTML Site 2 Page 4">
      <match url="Page1.html" />          
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^htmlsite1$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://htmlsite2/Page4.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```

Above rules are working fine with both rewrites. one is with in the site and other is rewriting to another site.

**URL Rewrite-1**

[image]

**URL Rewrite-2**

[image]

**Then**

I have hosted 2 IIS sites with few ".aspx" pages in that.

This application is sample asp.net web application which has "master" page in it.

Below is the Rewrite Rule I have it in my TestSite1 web config file.

```
<rule name="Rewrite testsite1 Menu Page to testsite1 Contact Page">
      <match url="Menu" />        
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testsite1$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Contact" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```

The above Rewrite is also working. (Rewriting to with in the domain)

**BELOW REWRITE NOT WORKING WHEN REWRITING TO ANOTHER SITE/DOMAIN**

I have another URL Rewrite across the domain as below config in my testsite1 web.config

```
    <rule name="Rewrite testsite1 About Page to testsite2 Menu Page">
      <match url="About" />       
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testsite1$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://testsite2/Menu" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```

**UPDATED**

- I hit the URL http://testsite1/About
- Expecting URL should not changed and expecting response from http://testsite2/About
- But Seems URL Rewrite is happened. I am getting the response from http://testsite1/About only.
- I do enabled FRT to diagnose this and found below from the log file.
- In the log file, I am seeing the below 2 times with the event "URL_CHANGED"
- First time it looks good.
- Second time, it changed back to actual URL. This is the issue and don't know why this is happened.

  ```
         <EventData>
         <Data Name="ContextId">{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
         <Data Name="OldUrl">/About</Data>
         <Data Name="NewUrl">http://testsite2/About</Data>
        </EventData>

         <EventData>
         <Data Name="ContextId">{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
         <Data Name="OldUrl">http://testsite2/About</Data>
         <Data Name="NewUrl">/About</Data>
        </EventData>
  ```

**FULL FRT EVENTS:**

```
            <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
         <System>
          <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
          <EventID>0</EventID>
          <Version>1</Version>
          <Level>5</Level>
          <Opcode>4</Opcode>
          <Keywords>0x400</Keywords>
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-09-21T12:24:50.218Z"/>
          <Correlation ActivityID="{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
          <Execution ProcessID="15492" ThreadID="27696"/>
          <Computer>XXXXXXXXXXX</Computer>
         </System>
         <EventData>
          <Data Name="ContextId">{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
          <Data Name="RuleName">Rewrite testsite1 About Page to testsite2 About Page</Data>
          <Data Name="RequestURL">http://testsite2/About</Data>
          <Data Name="QueryString"></Data>
          <Data Name="StopProcessing">false</Data>
          <Data Name="Succeeded">true</Data>
         </EventData>
         <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
          <Opcode>RULE_EVALUATION_END</Opcode>
          <Keywords>
           <Keyword>Rewrite</Keyword>
          </Keywords>
         </RenderingInfo>
         <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
          <EventGuid>{0469ABFA-1BB2-466A-B645-E3E15A02F38B}</EventGuid>
         </ExtendedTracingInfo>
        </Event>


        <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
         <System>
          <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
          <EventID>0</EventID>
          <Version>1</Version>
          <Level>5</Level>
          <Opcode>12</Opcode>
          <Keywords>0x400</Keywords>
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-09-21T12:24:50.218Z"/>
          <Correlation ActivityID="{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
          <Execution ProcessID="15492" ThreadID="27696"/>
          <Computer>XXXXXXXXXXXX</Computer>
         </System>
         <EventData>
          <Data Name="ContextId">{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
          <Data Name="Substitution">http://testsite2/About</Data>
          <Data Name="RewriteURL">http://testsite2/About</Data>
          <Data Name="AppendQueryString">true</Data>
          <Data Name="LogRewrittenURL">true</Data>
         </EventData>
         <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
          <Opcode>REWRITE_ACTION</Opcode>
          <Keywords>
           <Keyword>Rewrite</Keyword>
          </Keywords>
         </RenderingInfo>
         <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
          <EventGuid>{0469ABFA-1BB2-466A-B645-E3E15A02F38B}</EventGuid>
         </ExtendedTracingInfo>
        </Event>
        
        <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
         <System>
          <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
          <EventID>0</EventID>
          <Version>1</Version>
          <Level>4</Level>
          <Opcode>42</Opcode>
          <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-09-21T12:24:50.218Z"/>
          <Correlation ActivityID="{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
          <Execution ProcessID="15492" ThreadID="27696"/>
          <Computer>XXXXXXXXXXX</Computer>
         </System>
         <EventData>
          <Data Name="ContextId">{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
          <Data Name="OldUrl">/About</Data>
          <Data Name="NewUrl">http://testsite2/About</Data>
         </EventData>
         <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
          <Opcode>URL_CHANGED</Opcode>
         </RenderingInfo>
         <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
          <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
         </ExtendedTracingInfo>
        </Event>


        <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
         <System>
          <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
          <EventID>0</EventID>
          <Version>1</Version>
          <Level>4</Level>
          <Opcode>2</Opcode>
          <Keywords>0x400</Keywords>
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-09-21T12:24:50.218Z"/>
          <Correlation ActivityID="{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
          <Execution ProcessID="15492" ThreadID="27696"/>
          <Computer>XXXXXXXXXXX</Computer>
         </System>
         <EventData>
          <Data Name="ContextId">{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
          <Data Name="RequestURL">http://testsite2/About</Data>
         </EventData>
         <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
          <Opcode>URL_REWRITE_END</Opcode>
          <Keywords>
           <Keyword>Rewrite</Keyword>
          </Keywords>
         </RenderingInfo>
         <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
          <EventGuid>{0469ABFA-1BB2-466A-B645-E3E15A02F38B}</EventGuid>
         </ExtendedTracingInfo>
        </Event>

        <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
         <System>
          <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
          <EventID>0</EventID>
          <Version>1</Version>
          <Level>4</Level>
          <Opcode>42</Opcode>
          <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-09-21T12:24:50.218Z"/>
          <Correlation ActivityID="{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
          <Execution ProcessID="15492" ThreadID="27696"/>
          <Computer>XXXXXXXXXXX</Computer>
         </System>
         <EventData>
          <Data Name="ContextId">{40000045-0000-F200-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
          <Data Name="OldUrl">http://testsite2/About</Data>
          <Data Name="NewUrl">/About</Data>
         </EventData>
         <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
          <Opcode>URL_CHANGED</Opcode>
         </RenderingInfo>
         <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
          <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
         </ExtendedTracingInfo>
        </Event>
```

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 If you avoid common mistakes then things will start to work.

Comment: Thanks, Redirect works. But Rewrite not works. "Menu" page gives 404 when I enable the Rule. I have updated the Rules in my question now.

Comment: Mistake 3 it is.

Comment: I am following this URL to download and install ARR. But download location gives 404. I am using IIS 10 which comes with Windows 11. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/installing-application-request-routing-arr/install-application-request-routing-version-2#step-1---download-microsoft-application-request-routing-version-2

Comment: Tried from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing this location ARR 3. It's installed. But in IIS, i am seeing a new feature "ARR Cache" not "ARR" to enable it as provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Error 404 is NOT Found.  Either URL (route) is missing on the IIS or you do not have permission to access the route.  IIS you have limited access to the server resources such as file system.  The default access is GUEST,  If users need to access files on server place on a shared network drive where uses have access to the file system.  Webpages access files like json and html (different routes) which are on the server and client connections may not have access rights to read these files.

Comment: You say redirect works,Why doesn't your second rule's action type use a redirect?

Comment: when user hits the URL http://testsite1/menu, I want to keep the URL ASIS in the browser. But server should respond the page content from http://testsite1

Comment: You said that your another URL Rewrite across the domain does not work. I suggest you try using FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I have enabled the FRT and It looks under the REWRITE_ACTION, the expected URL is there. But Couldn't find why the URL Rewrite not happened.

Comment: I see the logs you provided indicate that the URL was indeed rewritten initially, but then changed back. Not sure what the specific cause is, you need to check if there are other rewrite rules enabled in IIS that may conflict with this rule. If there are conflicting rules, they may change the URL again after you intend to rewrite it. Also, check if there is a cache. Even if the rewrite is correct, the cached response may still reflect the old URL. Try clearing your browser cache or using a different browser or testing URL rewriting in private mode.

Comment: Yeah, I do have ensured that there are no rules in place, cleared app pool, restarted IIS, always using Private window to check this. Still could not figure out why rule is changing back the URL again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not specified all your IIS settings.

Maybe you have proxying requests configured in ARR `iis machine root node->Application Request Routing Cache->Server Proxy Settings->Enable Proxy=true` so redirects for sites with static content work correctly.

Maybe you have Server Farm configured for sites with dynamic content (aspx).

If this is the case, then the reason is that the address you specify in the redirect rule is the name of a record in Server Farms and when proxying in the headers it is not substituted, so the request does not reach testsite2, but goes to testsite1.

To fix this you either delete the Server Farms entry and use ARR proxying or use this rather uncomplicated solution https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/arr-change-the-hostname-on-re-routing-to-backend-node-the/ba-p/1340780